# ASP.Net MVC4 web application templete is not there in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I recently installed Visual Studio 2015.  I was not able to find the ASP.Net MVC4 web application template in it.

[image: screen shot]

Please let me know i have to download anything again.

Comment: Click OK > select `Empty` and select checkbox of `MVC` on under > click OK

Comment: No need to *download anything again*!

Comment: why it is looking different, i have selected MVC after selecting the ASP.Net web application, but  previously it is different. let me know why ?

Comment: As far as i know, VS 2015 changed the web site/ web project template a bit. In your first screen shot, you are creating an "Empty Website", which is implicitly denotes an MVC web site. After the selection you can add elements of your choice (like web forms, web pages etc). Same rule applied for the "Web Project" also. By selecting these options (ASP.Net Empty Website or ASP.Net Empty Web Application), VS 2015 helps you achieve "One ASP.Net" template.